# Clean ExtJS panel's on click of a grid cell

Tags: json, extjs, grid, panel

I have a grid (with one column) on the left and a Panel on the right. With every click on a cell of the grid I need to clear the existing data in the Panel and then load it with new data.

I am able to load the data but the problem is in clearing the existing data in the Panel. For e.g. Suppose a checkbox was checked before and in the new Data it's not checked. If I don't refresh it, the checkbox will still be checked.

Kindly tell me how do I clean the existing data of various components in the Panel.

Comment: If you are on Extjs 5 then http://extjs.eu/example-bind-grid-form/

Comment: I am on ExtJS 4 and this link doesn't help me. I have a panel with text fields and checkboxes and nested panels inside it. I need to clear the data of all fields so that no inconsistencies occur with the previously loaded data. Another example would be if I have a textfield with name 'hello' and the new data doesnt contain this field. So i need to show a blank value in this textfield. What is currently happening is that I am overriding the previous data. So in this case since there is no data to override the textfield will show 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the field from your form panel with a query and reset.

Query from sencha: [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query)

```
var arrayElements = Ext.ComponetQuery.query('myViewPanelID form'); // try to look for your component panel.
```

On second step, you need iterate all your components and reset all of them.

Sencha api: [iterate an Array](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.Array)

Sencha api: [Reset field](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.File-method-reset)

```
Ext.Array.each(arrayElements , function(el, index, elementItSelf) {
    el.reset(); 
});
```

Comment: I added the above lines and even though the console in the browser isn't showing any error the checkbox is still not being reset. Its still checked from the previous data even though the current data requires it to be unchecked.

Comment: try to make a debugging iteration for "arrayElements" Object and see if Check_Buttons are in the array.